# Procurar datas entre outras datas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Bom dia, eu tenho uma base de dados em Mongo DB assim:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5addb57d0043582d48ba898a"),
"base" : "EUR",
"date" : "2018-04-23",
"rates" : {
    "BRL" : 4.175076
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5addb57d0043582d48ba898a"),
"base" : "EUR",
"date" : "2018-04-24",
"rates" : {
    "BRL" : 4.185076
}

    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5addb57d0043582d48ba898a"),
"base" : "EUR",
"date" : "2018-04-25",
"rates" : {
    "BRL" : 4.205076
}
```

E em Python gostava de inserir uma data de inicio, neste caso dia 23 e uma data de fim, dia 25, e que de alguma maneira se possível também buscasse a informação que está entre essas duas datas que neste caso é do dia 24.
Eu já tenho o mongo conetado com a bd.

```
import pymongo

#conectar à bd
uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['db']
collection = database['currency']
collection2 = database['countries']

#Encontar dados na bd
p = str(input('Insira o país: '))
d = input('Insira a data no formato (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
item = collection.find_one({"date" : d})

if p == 'Brasil':
 d = collection.find_one({})
 item = collection2.find_one({"Pais": p})
 aj = item['ajudacusto']
 primeiramoeda = item['MoedaLocal']
 item2 = collection.find_one({})
 segundamoeda = item2['rates']['EUR']
 moedafinal = item2['rates'][primeiramoeda]
 res = (segundamoeda / moedafinal)
 res2 = res * aj
 print('Você ficou {} dias, que em ajuda de custo dará {:.2f}€'.format(dias, res2))
```

Obrigado a quem ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que basta você utilizar o método `find`, que retorna um cursor, não apenas um registro, passando um dicionário como filtro do seu campo data. Por exemplo:

```
inicio = datetime.date(2018, 4, 23)
final = datetime.date(2018, 4, 25)

collection.find({
    'date': {
        '$gte': inicio,
        '$lte': final
    }
})
```

Os operadores `$gte` e `$lte` são os operadores de maior ou igual e menor ou igual, respectivamente.

Comment: No caso de ser o utilizador a inserir as datas como ficaria?

Comment: Você captura os dados e gera os objetos `datetime.date`.