# Pegar valores entre duas datas e exibir no template do django

Tags: python, django

Tenho dois modelos, fluxo e relatório, no fluxo tem um campo data, e no relatório tem dois campos, data inicio e data fim, quero fazer com que o relatório exiba os registros no fluxo entre as datas selecionadas no relatório, da forma que fiz não retorna registro nenhum, segue o código:

**model relatório**

```
class Relatorio(models.Model):

data_inicio = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
data_fim  = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
def imprimir(self):
    return mark_safe("<a target='_blank' href='%s'>Imprimir</a>" % self.get_absolute_url())
    imprimir.allow_tags = True
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('fluxo_list', args=[self.pk, ])
```

O model do fluxo é composto somente pelo campo data

**Método do view:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    inicio = self.kwargs.get('data_inicio')
    fim = self.kwargs.get('data_fim')
    return dict(
        super(RelatorioDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs),   

        fluxo_list = Fluxo.objects.filter(data__range=[inicio, fim])


    )
```

Comment: Lucas, sua pergunta não ficou clara para mim. E se for possível colocar o model de fluxo também ajudaria.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Procurar datas entre outras datas em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298621/procurar-datas-entre-outras-datas-em-python)

Comment: Pergunta ainda muito obscura, onde esta esse tal "relatorio"? Cade a template? Pq não postar a view inteira?

Comment: Já olhou se não é o formato das datas? Porque no banco ele salva como 2020-20-03 e a entrada foi 20/03/2020